# Snap Action Switch SPDT - Electronic Symbol

Tags: switches

Does anyone knows if there is a certain electronic symbol for a "Snap Action Switch SPDT" like this at the below image?

[image]

Comment: you might like to look at this https://www.micromark.com/html_pages/instructions/82611i/82611microswitches.htm

Answer (score 1):

I would just show it as any other SPDT switch.  Additional text on the schematic would indictate the switch's function and style.